# Provide direct links to information pages in the mod menu on posts

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, moderator-tools

There are several moderator tools accessed from the `mod` menu on a post that open a page containing information about the post:

- show *N* deleted comments
- show flag history
- show review history

Often I'd like to open these pages in a new tab or window, to be able to switch quickly between the context of the post (the page I'm starting from) and the additional information that I'm interested in for one reason or another. Another reason to open these pages in a new tab is when I'm working from the moderator dashboard, so that I don't have to leave the dashboard, see the extra information, and then get back to the post to handle the flag.

Unfortunately, the tools operate by clicking on a `Submit` button which posts a form, rather than providing the URL to the target page, so that I can't easily middle-click or right-click and select “open in a new tab/window”. The information pages do all have distinct URLs that respond to GET requests, so this is purely a client-side UI limitation. Submitting a POST request makes sense for do-this tools like lock, protect, etc. but not for view-this tools.

Please change the mod menu to provide a direct link to the pages of the view-this tools, which can be seamlessly opened in a new tab or window if desired. The “timeline” link already works this way.

Comment: Basically, any idempotent method should be accessible via a link. Makes me wonder why the timeline was added in such a way while others were kept as-is.